# React.js passing path as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to pass path value to my pictures folder as property in React.js. Here is how i am doing that:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function importAll(r) {
    let images = [];
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
}

class CoverGallery extends React.Component {
   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderImgs() {
        console.log(this.props.location);
        const images = importAll(require.context(this.props.location, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));      
        console.log(images);
        let imagearray = [];
        for(var key in images) {            
            imagearray.push(<img key={key} className="galery" src={images[key]} alt="Description of the universe" ></img>);
        }
        return <div>{imagearray}</div>
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="photo-gallery">
                {this.renderImgs()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Blog extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CoverGallery location="../pictures/"/>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Blog />,
     document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If I replace this.props.location with "../pictures/" in renderImgs() everything works OK.

What is the reason behind this behaviour and how to overcome this issue?

Thanks!

EDIT:
What I am trying to do is image slideshow using all the images in specific folder location. Good old "import x from y" is not suitable because I don't know exact image count upfront.

Therefore, I am using Webpack to do that. How can I bypass Webpack requirement to know exact folder location upfront?

Comment: What is `require.context`? And what does your `r.keys()` in `importAll` actually contain in both instances? (e.g. "we don't know what your filesystem looks like, you probably want to help people understand what's going on by including as much detail as is relevant =)

Comment: Webpack bundles content, but it cant bundle stuff its not been told about.  You are passing a dynamic directory, its impossible at compile time to determine what the directory is.

Comment: How can I bypass Webpack requirement to know the exact folder location at compile time?

Comment: You could try altering your component to expect a context instead of a string.  You can pass most things to React props, the directory would then be known.  Another option, but much harder is to create a webpack plugin that could traverse the AST and extract the directories that way.